# How take more than one input and run the program for each one

Tags: fortran

The following is a program for self avoiding random walk. The program works fine but I need to make a minor modification but I do not know how.

Currently the program receives `n` and `ns` as inputs and then calculates a distance (`dis`). I want the program to receive more than one `n` and calculate the distance for each `n`.

Example of current output

```
n = 100 ns = 100 dis = 10.8
```

I want the program to output

```
  n = 100 ns = 100 dis = 10.8 

  n = 200 ns = 100 dis = 11.6
```

and go on for all input vales of `n`.

This can be done by running the program every time with different `n` but I need to do it with one run.

```
PROGRAM Two_dimensional_Self_Avoiding__Random_Walks

  implicit none

  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: lattice 
  integer :: i,x,y,xt,yt,id,step,xx, ns,n
  real :: r,dis,dis2,square,d,d2
  Logical :: terminate,newsite
  print*, ' Enter ns and n '
  read(*,*) ns,n 
  allocate(lattice(-n:n,-n:n)) 

  CALL RANDOM_SEED()
  dis = 0.0; dis2 = 0.0              ! intial values for end to end distance 
  CALL walks()                          ! self avoiding walks
  dis = dis/float(ns); dis2 = dis2/float(ns)
  print*,ns,n,dis,dis2


CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE walks


    DO i = 1,ns

    lattice = 0; x = 0; y = 0
    step = 0; terminate = .FALSE.
        !do ii = 1, n

    DO WHILE ((.NOT. terminate) .AND. (step <= n))
    xt = x; yt = y
    xx = lattice(x+1,y)+lattice(x-1,y) &
    +lattice(x,y+1)+lattice(x,y-1)

    IF (xx == 4) THEN
    terminate = .TRUE.
    ELSE
    newsite = .FALSE.

    DO WHILE (.NOT. newsite)
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(r)
    id = INT(r*4.0)

    IF (id == 0) THEN
    x = xt + 1; y = yt
    ELSEIF (id == 1) THEN
    x = xt - 1; y = yt
    ELSEIF (id == 2) THEN
    x = xt; y = yt + 1
    ELSEIF (id == 3) THEN
    x = xt; y = yt - 1 
    ENDIF

    IF (lattice(x,y) == 0) newsite = .TRUE.

    ENDDO

    step = step + 1; lattice(x,y) = 1
    ENDIF
    write(10,*),step
 !print*, x,y
    write(7,*) x,y
    ENDDO

    square = float(x**2+y**2)
    dis = dis + sqrt(square); dis2 = dis2 + square
    d = dis/ns; d2=dis2/ns

    write(8,*) step, d, d2

!enddo
    ENDDO

    END SUBROUTINE walks


END PROGRAM Two_dimensional_Self_Avoiding__Random_Walks
```

Comment: Why can't you just loop over reading the values in and call the walk routine for each one? You'll need a deallocate, something to indicate you have no more values, and possibly separate files for each run, but that's not at all difficult. Also it's good practice to avoid global variables wherever possible, and here every variable is global - use some local ones! When your programs get more complex you will make your life simpler by keeping the scope of each variable as limited as possible!

Comment: unrelated to the question, but your distance calculation makes no sense.